# htaccess to php with different name/variable combos

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have php that works awesome
But I wanna change it from showing variables to look like dirs

eg:

`example.com/?mode=page&page=15` to `example.com/page/15`

and

`example.com/?mode=pic&picid=136` to `example.com/pic/136`

however I only know of one way to do it, such as:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1&page [R]`

but that only works for one case, otherwise it 404s

I tried using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]` so that the whole path gets passed. However, this way it doesn't seem to pass the CSS in my pages.

I'm extremely confused...

Here's my htaccess file

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

IndexIgnore *


RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^css/styles\.css$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If still of concern: Is your base URI directly after the domain or localhost? If not You have to reference that in your path in the html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are rewriting ALL urls to

```
index.php?url=
```

So your CSS files also get "redirected" to "index.php?url=" eg

```
index.php?url=css/styles.css
```

So you need to add "conditions" to your .htaccess so that certain files (or directories) dont get "redirected". You can do this by using "RewriteCond" (conditions) before your "RewriteRule ".

For example to not "redirect" the css file "css/styles.css" you could do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^css/styles\.css$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If I go to example.com/asd it doesn't break the css. But if I type example.com/asd/asd or more than one variable then it breaks the css